# How to insert multiple select values to Database with PDO?

Tags: php, html, pdo

I have a form that have a multiple select options and when I run the insert query I get an `Array to string conversion error`.

I have tried **foreach**, but it doesn't still insert to the database and I get a blank page without error or foreach error.

**HTML**

```
<select multiple name="platform[]" id="platform">
    <option value="" disabled>בחר כמה מהאפשרויות</option>
    <option value="facebook">facebook</option>
    <option value="instagram">instagram</option>
    <option value="google">google</option>
    <option value="youtube">youtube</option>
    <option value="linkedin">linkedin</option>
</select>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $platform = $_POST['platform'];
    $advertising_history = $_POST['advertising_history'];
    $advertising_external = $_POST['advertising_external'];
    $period_of_time_office = $_POST['period_of_time_office'];
    $price_satisfaction_office = $_POST['price_satisfaction_office'];
    $service_satisfaction_office = $_POST['service_satisfaction_office'];
    $effectiveness_advertising_office = 
    $_POST['effectiveness_advertising_office'];
    $advertising_price_range = $_POST['advertising_price_range'];
    $effectiveness_advertising = $_POST['effectiveness_advertising'];
    $outweb_advertising = $_POST['outweb_advertising'];
    $outweb_location = $_POST['outweb_location'];
    $outweb_effectiveness = $_POST['outweb_effectiveness'];

    $valid = true;

    if ($valid) {
        try {
            $pdo = DB();
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("
                INSERT INTO client_form_5(
                    client_id,
                    advertising_history,
                    advertising_external,
                    period_of_time_office,
                    price_satisfaction_office,
                    service_satisfaction_office,
                    effectiveness_advertising_office,
                    platform,
                    advertising_price_range,
                    effectiveness_advertising,
                    outweb_advertising,
                    outweb_location,
                    outweb_effectiveness
                )
                VALUES (
                    :client_id,
                    :advertising_history,
                    :advertising_external,
                    :period_of_time_office,
                    :price_satisfaction_office,
                    :service_satisfaction_office,
                    :effectiveness_advertising_office,
                    :platform,
                    :advertising_price_range,
                    :effectiveness_advertising,
                    :outweb_advertising,
                    :outweb_location,
                    :outweb_effectiveness
                )
            ");

            $stmt->bindParam("client_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam("advertising_history", $advertising_history, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("advertising_external", $advertising_external, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("period_of_time_office", $period_of_time_office, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("price_satisfaction_office", $price_satisfaction_office, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("service_satisfaction_office", $service_satisfaction_office, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("effectiveness_advertising_office", $effectiveness_advertising_office, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("platform", $platform, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("advertising_price_range", $advertising_price_range, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("effectiveness_advertising", $effectiveness_advertising, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("outweb_advertising", $outweb_advertising, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("outweb_location", $outweb_location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam("outweb_effectiveness", $outweb_effectiveness, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to get in my db all the values options but instead I get just the word Array.

Comment: What were you expecting to see instead of `Array`?

Comment: Which line throws that error? What have you tried to solve or even debug that problem?

Comment: So what do you want `platform` to look like in the database being as it could contain more than one value as its an array

Comment: @NicoHaase The `bindParam` I would guess as OP is trying to load an array into it

Comment: **So how do you want to store these multiple selections**

Comment: @yosef-dadya Everyone here claims an expert, but they do not give any solution.
You are saving an array in a string field,
So you get an error,
To do you need to convert it to a string, with json_encode() you can make a string
And when you call the table from the database, use json_decode() this field to revert to the array

Comment: the json_encode() do the work for me its insert it like array inside the DB column thank you

Comment: **Don't forget the :**, for example `bindParam(":client_id"` [PDO Docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#example-1060)